# End response in constructor

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to do some checking in `WCF` before calling `Operation`.

My code is as below

```
public RESTService()
{
    if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("BlockLogin") == "1")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("{""Status"" : ""Service under maintainance""}");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
    }
}
```

I was expecting that it would end the request and won't call operation contract (getTokenX in this case) but it does. How to make it stop calling operation contract?

my URL is like

```
172.16.3.156:81/_RestAPI/RestService.svc/getTokenX
```

Comment: Performing any action except setting up an object in constructor is wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the Global.asax file to control the validity of the request.

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          if (Flag==true)
        {
            Response.End()
        }
    }
```

I don’t recommend using httpcontext in the wcf application. In most cases, It is set for the asp.net application domain and its value is empty.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-services-and-aspnet

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following thing for solution.

- Create custom service behaviour.
- In that service behaiour check for specific appsetting the way you do.
- if you found some value that indicate service in maintainance then throw exception.